# Is there a function $f$ such that $\Gamma (c+x)=\Gamma (c-f\left( x \right) )$?

Tags: special-functions, functional-equations, gamma-function

I was just looking at Euler's reflection formula for Gamma function which states $$\Gamma (1-z)\Gamma (z)=\frac { \pi  }{ \sin { (z\pi ) }  } $$ but it seems to me that one more reflection formula could exist so that $$\Gamma (c+x)=\Gamma (c-f\left( x \right) )?$$ where $c\approx 1.46163$ the local minimum for Gamma function where x>0.

Our first impressions would be that $$f\left( x \right) >f(y),\quad x>y\\ f(0)=0\\ f(2-c)=c-1\\ Im(f(x))=[0,c>$$.

Can such function exist, and still follow Euler's reflection formula?

Comment: f(x) = -x ?? would work...

Comment: no, not even closely, the function must be defined on the whole $[0,+infinity>$ while it's image must be $Im(f(x))=[0,c>$

Comment: it would be similar to arcus tangens function